# Unknown command 'DockerBuild' while installing sitecore 10 demo site

Tags: installation, docker

I am trying to install Sitecore Demo site (https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Platform) on my local using the steps mentioned in this guide  - https://buoctrenmay.com/2020/11/06/sitecore-xp-10-0-and-sxa-10-0-demo-lighthouse-setup-guide/

```
I am getting below error - 

Preparing to run build script...
Running build script...

Error: Unknown command 'DockerBuild'.



     build.cake -deploymentTarget=DockerBuild --Target Content-Management
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ No such command

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; .\build.ps1 -DeploymentTarget DockerBuild --Target Content-Management' returned a non-zero code: 1

ERROR: Service 'solution' failed to build : Build failed
```

Can anybody please suggest how to resolve this one? I am new to docker.

[image]

Comment: I assume that you have all the prerequisites, docker and environment preparations? Do you also have the 10.0 repo cloned correctly?

Comment: yes @CristiVulturar

Comment: I got same error as "Error: Unknown command 'Content-Management'.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark...

Please review Dockerfile located here:

> \docker\images\windows\demo-solution\Dockerfile

Look for line:

```
RUN .\build.ps1 -DeploymentTarget DockerBuild -Target Content-Management
```

From your error message, it looks like an additional '-' has been added to create --Target. Could you have accidentally added that? as it could potentially cause an issue.

One other thing, looks like the build.cake file is expecting argument starting with capital -DeploymentTarget. Whereas the build.ps1 file is passing it in as -deploymentTarget. Obviously this is a Sitecore repo... so very unlikely thats the issue, just a thought though...

Maybe look for line:

```
if ($DeploymentTarget) {$cakeArguments += "-deploymentTarget=$DeploymentTarget" }
```

and update to:

```
if ($DeploymentTarget) {$cakeArguments += "-DeploymentTarget=$DeploymentTarget" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had this similar kind of issue and I installed the required .NET core SDK, for building it needs .NET core CLI.

Hope this works for you.